# умножение слов в масме

Tags: masm32

При умножении 5 на 5 дает не 25, а 1.В чём проблема?Помогите найти.

```
.data
lpOut BYTE 4 dup (?)
formatString BYTE '%4d',0
.code
Main:
mov ax, 5
mov bx, 5
mul bx
push ecx
invoke WriteConsoleA, hStdout, offset newLine, sizeof newLine, 0, 0
invoke wsprintfA, offset lpOut, offset formatString, eax
invoke WriteConsoleA, hStdout, offset lpOut, sizeof lpOut, 0, 0
pop ecx
end Main
```

Comment: А первый WriteConsoleA случайно регистр eax не портит ?

Comment: Да, точно.Спасибо большое